# add TeamsTab as the first tab in the general channel using graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have working code to add a tab to the "General" channel of every team created. The users want the tab to be the first (default) of the "General" channel
Is there a way to do it?

```
    var channels = await graphClient.Teams[groupID].Channels.Request().Filter("displayName eq 'General'").GetAsync();
    var teamsTab = new TeamsTab
    {
        DisplayName = "Project KickOff",
        Configuration = new TeamsTabConfiguration
        {
            ContentUrl = $"https://{domain}/main.aspx?id={project.ProjectKickOff}",
            WebsiteUrl = $"https://{domain}/main.aspx?id={project.ProjectKickOff}"
        },
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"teamsApp@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.web"}
        }
    };
    TeamsTab tab = await graphClient.Teams[groupID].Channels[channels[0].Id].Tabs.Request().AddAsync(teamsTab);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any way to add any sort order while adding tab.